# How to remove a non-existent file in linux?

Tags: php, linux, copy, kill

I am writing a php program that is copying a large amount of files from the local mount to a backup mount.

In other words, `/var/www/some/dir` copy file to `/mnt/backup/some/dir`

I terminated the program mid-copy using ctrl-c. It was a test run where php was using `copy()` within a `foreach()` to put files in the backup.

Now I've got this file that I can see when I `ls -l`, but when I try to remove it I get an error that it doesn't exist.

[image: Trying to remove a file after terminating copy]

If you look at the quotes around the filename, there's something odd going on there. Character encoding?

What do I need to do to remove this file?

Comment: Check this out: http://serverfault.com/questions/545471/cannot-delete-file-with-rm-rf

Comment: FYI there's nothing weird about the quotes, that's how all messages of this type are printed.  Try `rm` on any other file, the message will look the same.

Comment: What's the filesystem used for /mnt/backup?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)